# Plain JavaScript code to highlight an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, dom

To debug some JavaScript code, I am looking for JavaScript code (preferably just js, without libraries and dependencies) that can highlight a `div` or `span` (probably by putting over it a div or span of the same size and shape with a bright color and some transparency).

I pretty sure it can be done, but I don't know how to start.

**CLARIFICATION**

I need to put a semi transparent `div` on top of my element. Modifying the background or adding borders will not help as my elements have themselves backgrounds and borders.

Comment: An outline will not affect the border of an element; it is rendered outside the border.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
element.style.backgroundColor = "#FDFF47";
```

#FDFF47 is a nice shade of yellow that seems perfect for highlighting.

**Edit for clarification:** You're over-complicating things. If you ever want to restore the previous background color, just store `element.style.backgroundColor` and access it later.

Comment: Doubt you'll get much simpler or effective than that.

Comment: Since I spent a bit of time on this: beware that (at least on Firefox 71) `element.style.backgroundColor` works only on *setting* the color if you use hex notation. If you need to *read it* and check it with an `if`, use Rgb notation.

Answer (score 14):

If you're debugging in a browser that supports the CSS `outline`, one simple solution is this:

```
myElement.style.outline = '#f00 solid 2px';
```

Answer (score 5):

---

If for some reason you need to use javascript here is function that temporary highlits element background

```
function highlight(element) {
    let defaultBG = element.style.backgroundColor;
    let defaultTransition = element.style.transition;

    element.style.transition = "background 1s";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#FDFF47";

    setTimeout(function()
    {
        element.style.backgroundColor = defaultBG;
        setTimeout(function() {
            element.style.transition = defaultTransition;
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Old post, but worth adding since it shows up in searches on the topic. A simple way to achieve a highlighting effect is:

```
myElement.style.filter = "brightness(125%)";
```

Comment: I love this answer, so elegant, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
function highlight(element) {
    var div = highlight.div; // only highlight one element per page

    if(element === null) { // remove highlight via `highlight(null)`
        if(div.parentNode) div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
        return;
    }

    var width = element.offsetWidth,
        height = element.offsetHeight;

    div.style.width = width + 'px';
    div.style.height = height + 'px';

    element.offsetParent.appendChild(div);

    div.style.left = element.offsetLeft + (width - div.offsetWidth) / 2 + 'px';
    div.style.top = element.offsetTop + (height - div.offsetHeight) / 2 + 'px';
}

highlight.div = document.createElement('div');

// set highlight styles
with(highlight.div.style) {
    position = 'absolute';
    border = '5px solid red';
}
```

Comment: Make sure to set `pointerEvents: 'none'` on `highlight.div` because you wouldn't want to highlight the highlight.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Firebug? It makes it very simple to identify dom elements and will highlight them in the page as you walk through the dom.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that combines the top 2 answers:

```js
function highlight(element){
    let defaultBG = element.style.backgroundColor;
    let defaultOutline = element.style.outline;

    element.style.backgroundColor = "#FDFF47";
    element.style.outline = '#f00 solid 4px';

    setTimeout(function()
    {
        element.style.backgroundColor = defaultBG;
        element.style.outline = defaultOutline;

    }, 2000);
}
```